# направление осей maya >unity

Tags: unity3d, 3d

как поменять направления осей готовой модели для экспорта из Maya в Unity? Вращая в майе pivot - меняются цифры rotate, freeze transformation обнуляет цифры, но меняет положение модели в пространстве. как в Maya изменить направление осей модели под Unity(т.е. Y  вверх, z - назад) не получая при этом вращения модели или изменения вращения её координат?

Comment: Ваш вопрос совершенно непонятен. Пожалуйста, добавьте скриншоты, скрипты, улучшите описание, подкорректируйте орографию и пунктуацию вопроса, иначе вскоре его закроют, как невозможный для ответа

Answer (score 0):

Возможны 2 варианта:

1. В maya измените pivot стандартно: D или Insert на клавиатуре.
2. В Unity добавить готовый объект в пустой GameObject и, повернув модель как вам нужно, вертеть уже его родителем(т.е. тем самым пустым объектом).

Comment: пустой обджект это костыль, хочется разобраться